# What is a more sophisticated term for 'needs'?

Tags: synonyms

What is the best term to replace the word 'needs' in the sentence quoted below?

> I feel obligated to apprise you of some problems between students and their needs

Nothing I found on Google seems to suit here, but the bare word 'needs' doesn't seem to do either.

Could you help, please?

Comment: You may mean *regarding* or *Involving* rather than *between*

Comment: What's wrong with using the word *needs*?

Comment: What is the context in which you're writing? It sounds like you're trying to elevate your diction by finding "fancy" synonyms, which unfortunately almost never comes off as eloquent, and in fact most native speakers can generally recognize this tactic, which makes whoever's using it seem *less* sophisticated--especially if you use a word in a non-idiomatic way because you're not familiar with it.

Comment: Jim is right. That "between" is off.

Comment: With no context, the word "needs" is so vague that the sentence could mean almost anything, and therefore it means almost nothing.. Try adding an adjective to make it more specific, for example "physical  / social / psychological / educational / dietary / healthcare / housing / recreational / whatever  needs"

Comment: Do you really mean "I feel obliged to let you know about some problems which involve the needs of the students"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Necessities](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/necessity) :

> - The conditions or qualities of being necessary. (AHD)

Comment: I saw this one, but wasn't sure whether I can use it in this sentence. Thanks ;).

Comment: @Fiodor I...wouldn't recommend it, actually. "Their necessities" would sound to me like some sort of allusion to the material "necessities" of life.

Answer (score 4):

"Requirements" could be a good substitution.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it is not the best word here. It's not necessarily something they require for a school, but well they need it. For example you might need that particular job, but not 'require' it. Just what I think, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I may have been thinking of "needs" as a noun in general.

Comment: I know. The word is good, but not really in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to aim high you could use ***[desiderata](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/desiderata)*** which is defined at that link as "things wanted or needed". Synonyms there include " essentials, necessities, requisites, sine qua nons"